# Matrix multiplication algorithms with lower time complexity than Strassen's algorithm

Tags: algorithm

**What I know:**
Naive matrix multiplication has time complexity of `O(n^3)` and [Strassen's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strassen_algorithm) has a time complexity of `O(2.81)`.
There exist few algorithms that have even lower time complexities, for example [Coppersmith–Winograd algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coppersmith%E2%80%93Winograd_algorithm), but the constant factor is so large that this algorithms are never used in practice.

**But i still want to know:**
Do there exist any actual programmed algorithms which I can try on my computer, or are these only theoretical algorithms? I want to see at least one implementation for one of the lower complexity algorithms, for example [this algorithm from Binni et. al.](https://doi.org/10.1016/0020-0190(79)90113-3) is one of the first introducing border rang and arbitary precision computing and I have no idea how could anyone implement this.

Again, I know that some of those algorithms are unusable in practice, but I still want to know if there exists any implementation as I haven't found anything after few hours of searching.

**Why I don't implement them myself?** Articles are strictly mathematical and they only provide a proof for time complexity
 I have no idea how algorithm would look.

Comment: *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow"*. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: What is preventing you from implementing the algorithms you are interested in?

Comment: I have no idea how to implement them. Articles are strictly mathematical and they only provide a proof for time complexity
 I have no idea how algorithm would look.